# Cosa significa "milza" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Il sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio*, di Vincenzo Consolo, ho letto:

> Il Mandralisca si trovò di fronte un uomo con uno strano sorriso sulle labbra. Un sorriso ironico, pungente e nello stesso tempo amaro, di uno che molto sa e molto ha visto, sa del presente e intuisce del futuro; di uno che si difende dal dolore della conoscenza e da un moto continuo di pietà. E gli occhi aveva piccoli e puntuti, sotto l’arco nero delle sopracciglia. Due pieghe gli solcavano il viso duro, agli angoli della bocca, come a chiudere e ancora accentuare quel sorriso. L’uomo era vestito da marinaio, con la **milza** di panno in testa, la casacca e i pantaloni a sacco, ma, in guardandolo, colui mostravasi uno strano marinaio: non aveva il sonnolento distacco, né la sorda stranianza dell’uomo vivente sopra il mare, ma la vivace attenzione di uno vivuto sempre sulla terra, in mezzo agli uomini e a le vicende loro. E, avvertivasi in colui, la grande dignità di un signore.

Sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "milza" in questo passaggio? Nei dizionari che ho consultato ho trovato solamente il significato anatomico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ho trovato in [Dialetti e idiomi d'Italia](http://forum.indire.it/repository_cms/working/export/5629/p_3_7a.html) proprio la spiegazione  del passaggio tratto dal libro da te citato:

> Non sempre le voci dialettali sono facilmente individuabili, come per
> esempio nel passo: "L'uomo era vestito da marinaio, con la milza di
> panno in testa, la casacca e i pantaloni a sacco", tratto da "Il
> sorriso dell'ignoto marinaio" di Vincenzo Consolo (1987), **la parola
> "milza" corrisponde al siciliano "meusa" che non solo significa
> "milza" ma anche "antico berretto, provvisto di una lunga falda
> posteriore" e che deve il suo nome alla forma simile a un milza.**

***Milza***, in siciliano, era quindi anche il nome di un antico berretto.

Comment: Non sono facilmente "individuali"?

Comment: Ho ricopiato tale e quale dal sito, è un refuso. Dovrebbe essere individuabili.